# Is there a non-blocking http client?

Tags: go

Many languages have their own high-level non-blocking HTTP client, for example, python's aiohttp. Namely, they send out HTTP requests; do not wait for response; When response arrives they make some kind of callbacks.

My questions are

1. is there a Go package for that?
2. or we just create a goroutine in which we use normal HTTP clients?
3. which way is better?

Comment: The goroutine feature is there to use.  Execute the request in a goroutine.

Comment: A go routine is the way to go. It is much simpler and convenient to use than callbacks.

Comment: Everything in Go is automatically "non blocking" if you call it in a goroutine.

Comment: this question lacks of useful sense in the world of go.

Comment: Thank you all! I am now feel confident in using the goroutine solutions!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Other languages have such features because when they block waiting for request they block the thread they are using. This is the case for Java, Python or NodeJS. Therefore to make them useful, the developers needed to implement such long-standing blocking operations with callbacks. The root cause of that is the usage of the C library beneath that blocks threads on input-output operations.

Go does not use C library (only in some cases, but it can be turned off) and makes system calls by itself. While doing this the thread that executes current goroutine parks it and executes another goroutine. Therefore you can  have enormous number of blocked goroutines without running out of threads. Goroutines are cheap with regard to memory, threads are operating system entities.

In Go using goroutines is better. There is no need for creating asynchronous client because of the above.

For comparison in Java you would quickly end up with multiple threads. The next step would be pooling them as they are costly. Pooling means limiting the concurrency.

Comment: Can someone please explain me this article then https://medium.com/@nate510/don-t-use-go-s-default-http-client-4804cb19f779 ? If the response is valid, how can long connections to a dependent service cause saturation?

Comment: @stillwaiting imagine an enormous number of blocked goroutines waiting for HTTP response from the external service forever. I mean, it would be not about resources, as the blocked ones are cheap, but about the app's liveness.

Comment: Not sure I follow, @o_nix (and thanks for the response :) )... If the enormous number of blocked goroutines is not about resources and it is cheap, then why the app won't be "live"...

Quote (from article): "Because API calls were being made to serve user requests, this caused the goroutines serving user requests to hang as well. Once enough users hit the sprockets page, the app fell over, most likely due to resource limits being reached." End quote.

This sounds like the starvation of the resources. Is it a mistake in the article, or I still miss something?

Comment: @stillwaiting OK, my bad, should've read the article more precisely, sorry. :) You are right, in this specific case, it was about resources as there is still no magic: more sleeping goroutines requested - more resources consumed. However, this answer emphasizes that you should be fine with requesting a big number of goroutines because they are not threads, as threads are consuming resources way much faster. I assumed a different situation: they were proxying the requests, and the requests just were hanging up because of indefinitely sleeping goroutines.

Answer (score 2):

As others have stated, goroutines are the way to go (pun intended).

Minimal Example:

```
type nonBlocking struct {
    Response *http.Response
    Error    error
}

const numRequests = 2

func main() {

    nb := make(chan nonBlocking, numRequests)
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}

    for i := 0; i < numRequests; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go Request(nb)
    }

    go HandleResponse(nb, wg)

    wg.Wait()

}

func Request(nb chan nonBlocking) {

    resp, err := http.Get("http://example.com")
    nb <- nonBlocking{
        Response: resp,
        Error:    err,
    }
}

func HandleResponse(nb chan nonBlocking, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {

    for get := range nb {

        if get.Error != nil {
            log.Println(get.Error)
        } else {
            log.Println(get.Response.Status)
        }
        wg.Done()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yip, built into the standard library, just not usable by a simple function call out of the box.

Take this example

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var url string
var timeout time.Duration

func init() {
    flag.StringVar(&url, "url", "http://www.stackoverflow.com", "url to GET")
    flag.DurationVar(&timeout, "timeout", 5*time.Second, "timeout for the GET operation")
}

func main() {
    flag.Parse()

    // We use the channel as our means to
    // hand the response over
    rc := make(chan *http.Response)

    // We need a waitgroup because all goroutines exit when main exits
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    // We are spinning up an async request
    // Increment the counter for our WaitGroup.
    // What we are basically doing here is to tell the WaitGroup
    // "Hey, there is one more task you have to wait for!"
    wg.Add(1)

    go func() {
        // Notify the WaitGroup that one task is done as soon
        // as we exit the goroutine.
        defer wg.Done()

        log.Printf("Doing GET request on \"%s\"", url)
        resp, err := http.Get(url)

        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("GET for %s: %s", url, err)
        }

        // We send the reponse downstream
        rc <- resp

        // Now, the goroutine exits, the defered call to wg.Done()
        // is executed.
    }()

    // And here we do our async processing.
    // Note that you could have done the processing in the first goroutine
    // as well, since http.Get would be a blocking operation and any subsequent
    // code in the goroutine would have been excuted only after the Get returned.
    // However, I put te processing into its own goroutine for demonstration purposes.
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {

        // As above
        defer wg.Done()

        log.Println("Doing something else")

        // Setting up a timer for a timeout.
        // Note that this could be done using a request with a context, as well.
        to := time.NewTimer(timeout).C

        select {
        case <-to:
            log.Println("Timeout reached")
            // Exiting the goroutine, the deferred call to wg.Done is executed
            return
        case r := <-rc:
            if r == nil {
                log.Printf("Got no useful response from GETting \"%s\"", url)
                // Exiting the goroutine, the deferred call to wg.Done is executed
                return
            }
            log.Printf("Got response with status code %d (%s)", r.StatusCode, r.Status)
            log.Printf("Now I can do something useful with the response")

        }
    }()

    // Now we have set up all of our tasks,
    // we are waiting until all of them are done...
    wg.Wait()
    log.Println("All tasks done, exiting")
}
```

If you look at this closely, we have all building blocks to make GETting an URL and processing the response async. We can start to abstract this a bit:

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

var url string
var timeout time.Duration

func init() {
    flag.StringVar(&url, "url", "http://www.stackoverflow.com", "url to GET")
    flag.DurationVar(&timeout, "timeout", 5*time.Second, "timeout for the GET operation")
}

type callbackFunc func(*http.Response, error) error

func getWithCallBack(u string, callback callbackFunc) chan error {

    // We create a channel which we can use to notify the caller of the
    // result of the callback.
    c := make(chan error)
    go func() {
        c <- callback(http.Get(u))
    }()
    return c
}

func main() {
    flag.Parse()

    c := getWithCallBack(url, func(resp *http.Response, err error) error {

        if err != nil {
            // Doing something useful with the err.
            // Add additional cases as needed.
            switch err {
            case http.ErrNotSupported:
                log.Printf("GET not supported for \"%s\"", url)
            }
            return err
        }
        log.Printf("GETting \"%s\": Got response with status code %d (%s)", url, resp.StatusCode, resp.Status)
        return nil
    })

    if err := <-c; err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error GETting \"%s\": %s", url, err)
    }
    log.Println("All tasks done, exiting")
}
```

And there you Go (pun intended): Async processing of GET requests.